# Rectangular cells versus square cells, is there some advantage?

Tags: raster, pixel, cell-size, square

I would say 100% of my work involving rasters is with rasters where the cell shape is *square*, e.g. 30m by 30m.

I recently received some NetCDF climate data and when I used ArcMap to visualise the layers I noticed the cells were *rectangular*. This [blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/what-happens-with-rectangular-raster-cells-in-spatial-analyst/) talks about how ArcMap deals with such data but I found myself asking why would anyone produce a raster where the cell shape was not square?

I've bumbled around on the internet looking for an explanation and failed to find any article on the pros and cons of rectangular versus square cells.

Is there a reason why someone would generate a raster with rectangular cells, is it for example some sort of clever space filling property for a global dataset?

Comment: There are many reasons, possibly as many as there are rectangular datasets.

Comment: Go on @Vince, don't leave me hanging, give me one reason why you might favour a rectangular-cell based raster. I ask as I have spent the whole of my career using only square-cell based rasters. Is it something specific to climate modellers for example?

Comment: Maybe EPSG:4326 pixels near the poles could be better as non-square so that the pixel size on the ground would be about the same in both directions. And when reprojecting data between coordinate systems it may lead to less resampling if pixels are allowed to turn into non-square.

Comment: DTED tiles switch to 2:1 then 3:1 near the poles. An oblique sensor angle could collect non-square pixels after georeferencing.